# Numba: Cannot determine the type of nested functions

Tags: python, numba

I have this numba script (in a file called 'MySource.py') i'm trying to compile:

```
from numpy import empty_like, inf, minimum, max
from numba import pycc

cc = pycc.CC('base_model')
cc.verbose = True


@cc.export('cumMin','float64[:](float64[:])')  
def cumMin(A):
    r = empty_like(A)
    t = inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = minimum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r

# nm -C base_model.so > bingo.txt
@cc.export('da_comp','List(float64)(float64[:, :])')  
def da_comp(rolled_ndarray):

    this_series_p = rolled_ndarray[:, 0]
    this_series_v = rolled_ndarray[:, 1]    

    return [max(cumMin(this_series_p)), max(cumMin(this_series_v))]

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

In bash, I do:

```
 python3 MySource.py
```

but I get a compilation error:

```
    raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'cumMin': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "MySource.py", line 24:
def da_comp(rolled_ndarray):
    <source elided>

    return [max(cumMin(this_series_p)), max(cumMin(this_series_v))]
```

I use numba 0.57.1 How to fix this?

#Edit:
I tried splitting the functions into two files as suggested in the answer by Eric below but this doesn't solve the issue (I get the same error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved the problem by replacing

```
@cc.export('cumMin','float64[:](float64[:])')
```

by:

```
@numba.jit(nopython = True)
```

```
import numpy
import numba
import numba.pycc

cc = numba.pycc.CC('base_model')
cc.verbose = True


@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def cumMin(A):
    r = numpy.empty(len(A))
    t = numpy.inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = numpy.minimum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r

@cc.export('da_comp','List(float64)(float64[:, :])')  
def da_comp(rolled_ndarray):

    this_series_p = rolled_ndarray[:, 0]
    this_series_v = rolled_ndarray[:, 1]    

    t1 = cumMin(this_series_p)
    t2 = cumMin(this_series_v)


    return [numpy.max(t1), numpy.max(t2)]

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()

#python3 MySource.py
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that `cumMin` is not recognized by numba as a proper type. Numba, when asked to compile with the `@cc.export`, doesn't look for dependencies in global scope, so `cumMin` is not found when compiling `da_comp`. A solution is to compile both methods seperately and then load the module before compiling the second method.

Here is a possible solution:

1. compile `cumMin` separately.

```
from numba.pycc import CC
from numba import njit

@njit('float64[:](float64[:])')
def cumMin(A):
    r = empty_like(A)
    t = inf
    for i in range(len(A)):
        t = minimum(t, A[i])
        r[i] = t
    return r

# numba.pycc.CC() returns an instance of a subclass of numba.pycc.CompilerBase
cc = CC('cumMin_module')

# Export cumMin function
cc.export('cumMin', 'float64[:](float64[:])')(cumMin)
cc.compile()
```

2. load resulting module and use it:

```
from cumMin_module import cumMin

cc = CC('base_model')
cc.verbose = True

@cc.export('da_comp','float64[:](float64[:, :])')  
def da_comp(rolled_ndarray):
    this_series_p = rolled_ndarray[:, 0]
    this_series_v = rolled_ndarray[:, 1]    
   
    return [max(cumMin(this_series_p)), max(cumMin(this_series_v))]

cc.compile()
```

3. run code with bash:

```bash
python3 MySource.py
```

This way `cumMin` is compiled first and then available in `da_comp`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but have you tried your code? I get the same error when I do what you propose:     `raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'cumMin': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

File "my_source_trial.py", line 12:
def da_comp(rolled_ndarray):
    <source elided>
   
    return [max(cumMin(this_series_p)), max(cumMin(this_series_v))]`